# Stream Myself And Allow Users To See Me

Tags: javascript, streaming

I'd like to stream myself and let the users view me, I've found this script online:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    
   
<video id="video" width="640" height="480" autoplay></video>
    
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
<script>
// Grab elements, create settings, etc.
var video = document.getElementById('video');

// Get access to the camera!
if(navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
        //video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.srcObject = stream;
        video.play();
    });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This script works well, the browser asks the user to turn on the camera and he gets shown in real time on his computer. Anyway I'd like that other users can see him live. what can I do?

Comment: You would need some server side communication.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon thanks for your answer :) I know I'd need server side communciation and I've thought about node.js, is there some tutorial on how to create a live streaming system? I'm not going to create a social media, just stream myself

Comment: If I'm being honest, I have absolutely no idea. I am not the correct person to ask, since I have never used node.js (or anything to do with servers). What you can do, however, is add some other tags onto your question.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon Oh well, why did you answer then? which tags should I add?

Comment: I wanted to give you a direction since I know js's capacities and nobody else answered.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon ok thanks anyway...

Comment: You can node.js and server-side to start off with.

Comment: @Endothermic_Dragon I know but I'd like to find a streaming strategy first, because I really don't know how to stream me. I've found that script I shared in this question and it is able to stream you but every user will see himself, not the real streamer

Comment: This question is way to broad for Stack Overflow. And unfortunately asking for off-site resources such as tutorials is also off-topic. See the [help] for what kind of questions you [can](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) ask.